# No boot sector found on internal hard drive after rebooting due to read only system error

Tags: boot, hard-drive, hardware

I have two disks (a 7 month old Kingston 240 GB SSD and a 9 year old western digital 250 GB HDD). I bought the SSD after my HDD started showing signs of failure (bad sector input error). Since then, I have been using SSD as a primary disk to boot and HDD as a secondary drive on CD/DVD drive.

Today when I booted my laptop, it started showing me `read only system` errors.

I rebooted and it now it shows no boot sector found on internal hard drive during booting.

When I ran system tests, it was showing:

```
dst hard drive test fail.
```

When I plugged SSD into my brother's desktop (Windows) disk management utility shows uninitialized disk and for HDD, but it shows partition intact.

What should I do? Please suggest

Edit Reason - **More information after running boot-info using a live usb**
For SSD -- boot-info summary [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SmRtctwn6y)
For HDD -- boot-info summary [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FKJrXTdwyF)
Also, I can access the files in both partition of HDD using live usb. But for SSD it is showing **unknown disk**
I think something is wrong with my SSD.

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred I have added the urls of boot-info summary.

Comment: You may be correct that drive is broken. Script sees that you have drive which is a good thing, but it is as if it is blank. I might try testdisk and photorec to see if they see anything. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step and http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step